# How should I write code for -nostartfiles or -nostdlib options for gcc?

Tags: c, gcc

I came across `-nostartfiles` and `-nostdlib` options under gcc compilation options. I, however, do not understand as to how one can write code for the above options. Do you need to write every startup function (like `_start`, `__libc_csu_init` etc.)?

Can I get a simplified code for both these options just to understand it's working?

**Edit**:

Also I just discovered that using `static` along with `nostartfiles` throws a `segmentation fault`. A simple c code to reproduce the same:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void _start()
{
    int x = main();
    exit(x);
}

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled using:

```
gcc -nostartfiles -static -o foo foo.c
```

The output to the above code is a `segmentation fault`. Is it the expected output?

Comment: Did you reach any answer since then?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is expected behaviour.
If you want to write your own startup-code or your own standard library, you need these options, otherwise you could not write your own code as symbols would be duplicated.

Comment: I want to understand as to how I can write complete startup myself. Are there any resources available online (I was unable to find any, hence the question)?

Comment: But, to clarify, the segfault occurred because there were no startup routines defined (apart from `_start()`)?

Comment: In your startup code, you would need to initialize static variables etc. That is probably something you missed. You will probably have to do this in assembler before using any code from the stdlib. Take a look into the startup code provided with your compiler, as (especially when you cross-compile) it is very much dependant on your target platform.